# Parsing JSON string from python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am working on a terrarium controller project, at this moment I want to get the timeperiod of the lighting. In python I have a function called: getStatus() it returns a JSON string to Javascript, which will handle the data further. But it doesn't work.

Here's my python code:

```
def getStatus ():
    data=[["HOUR_ON", HOUR_ON],["MINUTE_ON", MINUTE_ON], ["HOUR_OFF", HOUR_OFF], ["MINUTE_OFF", MINUTE_OFF]]
    return json.dumps(data)
```

And overhere the Javascript:

```
var alertFunction = function macroCallback(macro, args, light) {
    alert(macro + " returned with " + light);
    var obj = JSON.parse(light);
    document.getElementById("testSection").innerHTML="Light turns on at: "+ obj[0].HOUR_ON+":"+obj[0].MINUTE_ON + "\n"+"Light goes out at: "+obj[1].HOUR_OFF+":"+obj[1].MINUTE_OFF;
    alert("after parsing: "+obj[0]);
    document.getElementById("testSection").innerHTML=light;
}
```

The string seems to be send back from the server and will be parsed correctly, only accessing the string doesn't work I get four times undefined in the innerHTML section.

I hope someone can help me out!

Greetings and thanks!

Marco

Comment: Can you show a sample string returned by your Python function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your Python code, alter your javascript code to access the elements of the array using indices, not with attributes:

```
var alertFunction = function macroCallback(macro, args, light) {
    alert(macro + " returned with " + light);
    var obj = JSON.parse(light);
    document.getElementById("testSection").innerHTML="Light turns on at: "+ obj[0][1]+":"+obj[1][1] + "\n"+"Light goes out at: "+obj[2][1]+":"+obj[3][1];
    alert("after parsing: "+obj[0]);
    document.getElementById("testSection").innerHTML=light;
}
```

However, it would be better to follow [jcubic's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059783/21945) and change your Python code to use a dictionary:

```
def getStatus ():
    data={"HOUR_ON": HOUR_ON,
          "MINUTE_ON": MINUTE_ON,
          "HOUR_OFF": HOUR_OFF,
          "MINUTE_OFF": MINUTE_OFF}
    return json.dumps(data)
```

For example this produces a JSON string like this:

```
'{"HOUR_OFF": 13, "MINUTE_ON": 30, "MINUTE_OFF": 20, "HOUR_ON": 12}'
```

Also change your javascript to access the attributes of the object, which is much more readable:

```
var alertFunction = function macroCallback(macro, args, light) {
    alert(macro + " returned with " + light);
    var obj = JSON.parse(light);
    document.getElementById("testSection").innerHTML="Light turns on at: "+ obj.HOUR_ON + ":" + obj.MINUTE_ON + "\n" + "Light goes out at: "+obj.HOUR_OFF+":"+obj.MINUTE_OFF;
    alert("after parsing: "+obj[0]);
    document.getElementById("testSection").innerHTML=light;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've saved array instead of object try:

```
data=[{"HOUR_ON": HOUR_ON},{"MINUTE_ON": MINUTE_ON}, {"HOUR_OFF": HOUR_OFF}, {"MINUTE_OFF": MINUTE_OFF}]
```

or better just one object:

```
data={"HOUR_ON": HOUR_ON, "MINUTE_ON": MINUTE_ON, "HOUR_OFF": HOUR_OFF, "MINUTE_OFF": MINUTE_OFF}
```